# Local project.json (keeping out of SCM)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

For testing purposes, I'd like to run some post-compile scripts (some xcopy stuff etc.) declared within the `project.json` scripting part. However since I need to work with absolute paths and other local things, there's no point in putting the scripts into an SCM.

So, simple question: Is there a way to have multiple `project.json` (e.g. `project.local.json`) or reference multiple ones, so Visual Studio uses them aswell?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible.

However, an alternative would be to always call a script from `project.json` and then make it no-op when running under certain conditions. Or make that script able to run a second script if it exists, otherwise no-op.